# Simple CefSharp application is missing files at runtime

Tags: .net, cefsharp

This is probably a very simple question.
I copied the example CefSharp MinimalExample.WinForms project to a new directory and renamed to WinProxy.
It builds ok. When I run it I get;

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Comparing with the example directory, I am missing a number of files listed here https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution)

I do have CefSharp.Core.dll, CefSharp.WinForms.dll and CefSharp.dll which were all referenced in the example project.

How do I get the rest? I tried copying them over and rebuilding but I get;

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: A procedure imported by 'CefSharp.Core.dll' could not be loaded.

Thanks.

Comment: Did `CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms` run before you made your modifications? The `unmanaged` dependencies are copied by the `Nuget` package on build. Try removing the `CefSharp.WinForms` package and reinstalling it.

Comment: I uninstalled all the NuGet packages and then tried to reinstall them. cef.redist.x64 & cef.redist.x86 installed but CefSharp.Common won't. It says, Unable to resolve dependencies. 'cef.redist.x64 3.2526.1347' is not compatible with 'CefSharp.Common 45.0.0 constraint: cef.redist.x64 (= 3.2454.1344)'

Comment: Check your packages source, make sure `Nuget.org` is ticked.

Comment: https://www.myget.org/F/cefsharp/ and https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ are ticked in VS tools->options->NuGet Package Manager

Comment: If you untick the `myget` feed things should start to work again. I'm in the process of releasing the next release version `45.0.0`, so you've kinda been caught in a limbo period where packages haven't been uploaded to `Nuget.org` yet. Also incase your not aware, `CefSharp` required `VC++` to run, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#version-branches for details.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't seem to find cef.redist.x86 on NuGet, it is a dependency of Cef.Sharp.Common even though right now I would be happy with only x64.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/cef.redist.x86/

Comment: The `45.0.0` release is up on `Nuget.org` now, it might be worth re downloading the `MinimalExample`, making sure it works, then making your modifications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95971/discussion-between-p-hemans-and-amaitland).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussions with @amaitland I ended up uninstalling all NuGet packages and installing each package through the Package Manager Console;

```
Install-Package cef.redist.x86
Install-Package cef.redist.x64
Install-Package CefSharp.Common
Install-Package CefSharp.WinForms
```

It then worked.

Answer (score 6):

Install:

- Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013

Check:

- CefSharp Version 49.0.1 require Framework 4.5.1.
- CefSharp Version 51.0.0 require Framework 4.5.2 or later.

Compile Solution:

- x86 or x64

Comment: I was missing the Redistributable Package. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try check whether you have all following dependencies included?
[image]

Comment: If everything installed properly, you will find all above mentioned dll's

Comment: Can you please edit the answer to reflect where those dlls are coming from ie (packages.config or other sys dependencies that need to be installed)