# local deployment of Visual c++ for wpf application ( required for cef sharp )

Tags: c#, windows, cefsharp, setup-deployment, vcredist

I am looking for local deployment of visual c++ redistributable along with my x86 WPF application. The VC++ (2015 and greater) is required for CefSharp control that I am using. CefSharp version: 79.1.360

I tried copying files from below location to my application directory but none of these worked for me.

1. Universal CRT SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\DLLs\x86
   Which is mentioned [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/)
2. VC++ files from C:\Windows\System32 , mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755445/how-to-include-vc-redistributable-files-needed-by-cefsharp)
3. All files from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012\x86
   As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755445/how-to-include-vc-redistributable-files-needed-by-cefsharp)
4. All files from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules
   as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-components-by-using-merge-modules?view=vs-2019)
5. All files mentioned at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=vs-2019)

Files used from Windows SDK are:

```
api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-console-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
API-MS-Win-core-xstate-l2-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-private-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
ucrtbase.dll
```

Files from vc++ redist installation:

```
concrt140.dll
mfc140.dll
mfc140chs.dll
mfc140cht.dll
mfc140d.dll
mfc140deu.dll
mfc140enu.dll
mfc140esn.dll
mfc140fra.dll
mfc140ita.dll
mfc140jpn.dll
mfc140kor.dll
mfc140rus.dll
mfc140u.dll
mfc140ud.dll
mfcm140.dll
mfcm140d.dll
mfcm140u.dll
mfcm140ud.dll
msvcp140.dll
msvcp140_1.dll
msvcp140_2.dll
vcamp140.dll
vcamp140d.dll
vccorlib140.dll
vcomp140.dll
vcomp140d.dll
vcruntime140.dll
```

Comment: What versions of Windows do you need to support? What are the exact files you've included?

Comment: Hello @amaitland Thanks for reverting back.

I am looking for windows 10. The file names that I have included are:

concrt140.dll
mfc140.dll
mfc140chs.dll
mfc140cht.dll
mfc140d.dll
mfc140deu.dll
mfc140enu.dll
mfc140esn.dll
mfc140fra.dll
mfc140ita.dll
mfc140jpn.dll
mfc140kor.dll
mfc140rus.dll
mfc140u.dll
mfc140ud.dll
mfcm140.dll
mfcm140d.dll
mfcm140u.dll
mfcm140ud.dll
msvcp140.dll
msvcp140_1.dll
msvcp140_2.dll
vcamp140.dll
vcamp140d.dll
vccorlib140.dll
vcomp140.dll
vcomp140d.dll
vcruntime140.dll

Comment: MS redistributables are required to use the MS installer by license. You can't just grab files and distribute them yourself. Use of a MS insaller **must** be used.

Comment: @KenWhite the Microsoft documentation says otherwise https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/universal-crt-deployment?view=vs-2019#local-deployment Whilst it's not recommend it is allowed.

Comment: @amaitland: Read the second paragraph of the deployment section in the link you provided. It also specifically mentions Windows XP.

Comment: @KenWhite What's the relevance exactly? See also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/ they specifically amended the blog to say app local is support.

Comment: The VS2017 license section is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/2017-redistribution-vs#visual-c-runtime-files

Comment: The VS2015 license section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/2015-redistribution-vs#visual-c-runtime-files

Comment: The VS2019 license section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/redistribution#visual-c-runtime-files

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for clarifying and adding details for the KenWhite's doubt on this.

The local deployment is required to avoid the admin privilege for MS redistributable installer.

Comment: I generally still recommend using the installer, it saves a lot of hassle, Windows then takes over ownership of updating VC++. If you are targeting only `Windows 10` then you only need the `VC++` dlls as the Universal CRT comes as part of the OS. You should only need the files from `VC\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012\x86\Microsoft.VC141.CRT` folder. The `MFC` files aren't required. If you've included the 6 dlls in your bin folder then it's likely something else is causing a problem. I'd suggest using a Virtual Machine for testing and installing the `VC++ Redist` to confirm the software works.